# Why does God care so much about Details

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, kiruv-outreach

Kizayis, Kebeitzah, Toich Kedai Achilas Pras, Zman Kriyas Shemah

Why is god so into details what are their significance(e.x why does god care if I daven after Zman Kriyas Shemah)?